# JavaScript calculation returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to find total sum of passing the field values in array. If the field is for discount then perform minus else plus. For some reason I'm getting nan.

### Here is my script code

```
<script>

    var partial_cost = $('#bill_amount:disabled').val();
    var fine = +$('#fine').val();
    var discount = +$('#discount').val();
    var other_cost = +$('#other_cost').val();
    var total_cost = +$('#total').val();

    var chargeAble = [
    partial_cost,
    fine,
    discount,
    other_cost
    ];

    $.each(chargeAble, function (chargeIndex, charge) {
        charge.blur(function () {
            var amount = 0;
            for(charge in chargeAble)
                if(chargeAble[charge].attr('id') == 'discount')
                    amount -= (chargeAble[charge].val());
                else
                    amount += (chargeAble[charge].val());

                total_cost.val(amount);
            });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: For `fine`, `discount`, `other_cost`, `total_cost`, call `.val()` on it. Example: `var fine = +$('#fine').val();` And make sure code runs when DOM is completely loaded.

Comment: Thank you, that prevented from getting NaN but I'm still not getting the calculated value.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to add complete code with HTML and add live snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is using a combination of `.each()` AND a for-in loop... and strangely the callback from a `blur()` function? It can be simplified like this:

```
var amount = 0;
$('#bill_amount:disabled, #fine, #discount, #other_cost')
  .blur()
  .each(function() {
    var sign = this.id === 'discount' ? -1 : 1;
    amount += parseFloat($(this).val()) * sign;
  });
$('#total').val(amount);
```

---

Update:

Oh, you want the total to update on blur... try this code:

```
var $values = $('#bill_amount:disabled, #fine, #discount, #other_cost');
$values.on('blur', function() {
  var amount = 0;
  $values.each(function(){
    var sign = this.id === 'discount' ? -1 : 1;
    amount += parseFloat($(this).val()) * sign;
  });
  $('#total').val(amount);
});
```

Comment: thank you, but now I'm getting some calculation errors due to loop.
Eg. If I enter discount = 5 and fine = 5.
It performs -15.

Answer (score 0):

I can see stuff like this all around:

```
var fine = +$('#fine');
```

The `jQuery()` method returns `jQuery` objects, not numbers or even strings. Forcing a number cast will thus return `NaN`.

You need to first grab the text inside and than parse numbers of out it. How to do it depends on how your HTML is structured but in general:

- In form fields you can normally use `.val()`
- In most other tags you can use `.text()`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all values are interpreted as numbers by JavaScript. Otherwise it will try to calculate some odd result from a string, which might get interpreted as something else than the a decimal number (hex, octa, ...).

Answer (score 0):

You array holds numbers and you act like they are strings

```
var chargeAble = [  //this holds values
    partial_cost,
    fine,
    discount,
    other_cost
];
```

and in the loop you are using it for an id???

```
chargeAble[charge].attr('id')
```